# awk do math between lines

Tags: bash, awk

i'd like to put an empty line between lines which $1 differ > then 1.

thats the code sample:

```
104 9  
110 8
111 5
116 6
117 7
130 11
131 16
132 15
133 10
134 6
146 8
147 8
148 8
```

the try was:

```
awk '{a=$1; b=$2; getline; c=$1; d=$2; if (c-a>1) print a"\t"b"\n"c"\t"d;else print "\n"}' file
```

but the result is mixed up:

```
110     8
111     5
116     6
117     7
130     11
131     16
132     15
133     10

147     8
148     8
```

what i'm missing?

Comment: You are dropping lines because of your `getline`. Your `else` case only prints the second "current" line. You don't want `getline` anyway. Just write the code to store the line until the next line is seen and *then* print it.

Comment: `getline` should not be tackled until you have mastered every other part of awk. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline for details.

Answer (score 4):

This awk should work:

```
awk 'NR>1 && $1>p+1{print ""} {p=$1} 1' file
104 9

110 8
111 5

116 6
117 7

130 11
131 16
132 15
133 10
134 6

146 8
147 8
148 8
```